# Lambda expression to contrast different objects

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have two lists, one of contacts and the other of employees.  I want to generate that subset of contacts that are not employees.  The following expression seems to work in telling me that there are some contacts who are not employees, now I need a list of contacts that match that criteria:

```
if(myContacts.Select(c=>c.contactID).Except(employees.Select(e=>e.contactID)).Any()
{
   //get the subset of contacts and do stuff to them....
}
```

TIA!

Ron

Comment: Question: are contacts and employees the same class type or different (affects the answer)?  i.e. are they both `Person` or some such object sequence?  Or is one `Contact` and one `Employee`, etc...

Comment: If they are the same type (or both related to a base class where they pick up `contactID` then you can use an `EqualityComparer` like my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that these types are different types. They share a common Id.  They are also both in-memory lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `employees` and `contacts` sequences are the same type object (or both inherit from same type, like `Contact`), then you could create an `EqualityComparer` instance:

```
public class ContactComparer : EqualityComparer<Contact>
{
    public override bool Equals(Contact x, Contact y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        return x != null && y != null && x.ContactId == y.ContactId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Contact obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

        // assuming string
        return (obj.ContactId ?? "").GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Which would let you do this, thus you could just return the results directly and not have to double-query:

```
var contactsNotEmployees = myContacts.Except(employees, new ContactComparer()).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**: with Contact and Employee being separate types as your comment indicates, you can consider creating an interface with the ContactId property to create a common bond.

Or, I'd suggest exporting your except results to a `HashSet` and then use the `Contains()` from the `HashSet`, which is O(1) efficiency (instead of `Contains()` on a sequence, which is O(n) efficiency):

```
 // get hash set of contact-only IDs
 var except = new HashSet<int>(contacts
      .Select(c => c.ContactId)
      .Except(emplopyees.Select(e => e.ContactId)));

 // get the objects for those IDs
 var others = contacts.Where(c => except.Contains(c.ContactId)).ToList();
```

Comparing the results of using the sequence `Contains()` and the `HashSet` `Contains()` you're about 50% faster for small lists (15 items), even faster for longer lists.

Anyway, just throwing that out there, since Contains() on a sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`) is relatively slow...

I timed both solutions over 1,000,000 iterations and got:

```
 HashSet With Contains() took: 1429 ms, 0.001429 ms/item.
 Sequence With Contains() took: 3386 ms, 0.003386 ms/item.
```

Comment: James, this is a very nice routine, but unfortunately, I gave you incomplete specs - they are disparate types.

Comment: @Ron: Updated to fit your specs.  The main thing I worry about with the use of the sequence `Contains()` is that it's relatively slow - O(n) linear time - which is why if you want something like that, you could use a `HashSet` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gonna have to go with the data.  Obviously, both approaches work, but this is definitely worth the extra 10 minutes of coding.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
 var nonEmployees = contacts.Where(w=> ! employees.Any(e=>e.contactID == w.contactID)).ToList();
```

or

```
 var nonEmployees = contacts.Where(w=> ! employees.Select(s=>s.contactID).Contains(w.contactID) ).ToList();
```

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: I'm not sure we can do any better with the information provided can we?

Comment: We could create a custom EqualityComaparer, like @JamesMichaelHare recommends, assuming that Contact and Employees are at least from the same base class ... But, if the lists are small and in-memory, wouldn't the comparer be more expensive?

Comment: Yep, relatively small in-memory lists.  Thanks, this is what I was trying.  I'm still learning lambda expressions (obviously), but I'd already trade my bread slicer for them.....

Comment: Still, Contains on a sequence is heavier than if you took it to a hash set first.  The concept is spot-on, could benefit from a HashSet for speed.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this already what you're looking for?

```
myContacts.Select(c=>c.contactID)
          .Except(employees.Select(e=>e.contactID)
          .ToList()
```